# MySQL IS NULL alternative

Tags: mysql

I have a query that compares 2 tables:

```
SELECT a.id FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Is that ok to use an alternative like that?

```
SELECT a.id FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE LENGTH(b.id) = 0
```

Keeping in mind that a.id not found in b would return 'NULL'.

Comment: Why do you want to use the alternative?

Comment: Cause the first runs extremely slow (but seems the right way). Testing the second way, is so more fast, that looks wrong.

Comment: These queries are not the same. `LENGTH(b.id) = 0` is true when `b` is an empty string. It's not true when `b` is null.

Comment: For speed purposes try rewriting the query using `NOT EXISTS`. In some particular cases (I believe these ones were not your actual queries) it may give you some benefit.

Comment: If the first one runs extremely slow, try using EXPLAIN to figure out why. Maybe using WHERE NOT EXISTS would be faster?

Comment: @Karolis, in a brief test, NOT EXISTS looks much more fast. I gonna write the whole query, test with actual data and post the results later. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you'd like that but anyway, it's not correct to change to your second query. `length(b.id)` will return null, not 0, for rows in b not matchin rows in a.

This is easy to test, like I did on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4e2db/12).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not as LENGTH method will return NULL if b.id is not found and not zero.